# IR distance sensor

Tags: sensors

I am trying to make a IR distance sensor. I have seen [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-IR-proximity-sensor-with-Arduino/) online. My goal however is to see the distance between a IR transmitter and my IR sensor. In the example above he uses the IR led's ambient light and timing to track the distance. Is there a way to find the distance between lets say a IR remote and a sensor? It would only have to be accurate to about 1 meter. I am also open to other ideas of accurately tracking distance between two objects weither that be bluetooth/ir/ultrasonic

Comment: If you don't have an accurate way of knowing what the start time for the distance measurement is then you won't be able to do this. Distance is speed*time so if you don't know the time you are stuffed.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree that the stereoscopic technique will probably give you a better result. To implement this you have 2 options, either 1 led and 2 cameras or (I think the better option) 2 leds and 1 camera (which is the technique they used with the wiimote). You can see the second approach [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd3-eiid-Uw)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off setting up something that uses a stereoscopic technique. Think of something like [this](http://www.tobii.com/xperience/products/). Another similar product is the Leap Motion.

In your case, you could probably get away with just two IR sensors, and one emitter, because of your setup. However, "accurate to 1 meter" is not realistic for most kinds of IR rigs. They usually only function *within* 0.5 meters, but can be pretty accurate when tracking something inside of their range.